# Send data to firestore inside a worker in Android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, androidx, android-workmanager

I am trying to send the location of the phone every 15min to Firestore.

I was looking at workers in Android but what I have read my code wont work since they are synchronous and I am calling a asynchronous method to call firestore.

Also the contest I get inside the worker is a `MultiDexApplication` type and will throw a exception when calling         `mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()`

Here is the code for my worker.

```
public class LocationWorker extends Worker {
    private final static String TAG = "LocationWorker";

    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private Context mApplicationContext;
    private FirebaseFirestore mFireStoreRef;
    private String mCurrentUserID;

    public LocationWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters params) {
        super(context, params);
        mApplicationContext = getApplicationContext();
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(mApplicationContext);
        mFireStoreRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mCurrentUserID = "Patrick";

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener((Activity) mApplicationContext, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final Location location) {
                        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                        if (location != null) {

                            mFireStoreRef
                                    .collection("locations")
                                    .document(mCurrentUserID)
                                    .collection(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()))
                                    .add(location)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                                            Log.d(TAG, "Location added: " + location.toString());
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                    }
                });
        return Result.success();
    }
}
```

I get I cant make asynchronous calls inside the worker. But then I am wondering how I can get the location of the phone every 15min to be sent to firestore?

Comment: The fact that Firestore's API is asynchronous doesn't prevent you from using it with Jetpack Workmanager.  You have two options.  1) WorkManager offers async APIs as well (you return a ListenableFuture that resolves with the result of your work.  2) Make the worker thread block until the call is done, and a CountDownLatch is a common solution.  Option 1 is really the right way to do it.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks! I will try that right by the way. Do you know anything about getting the AppContext during a worker and not MultidexApplication when calling getApplicationContext()?

Answer (score 1):

There's a context passed into the Worker's constructor. If you're concerned about using it directly, you can try storing it in a WeakReference.

When using a ListenableWorker, the threading is up to you. This example runs everything inside of the Runnable created for the new Thread but you can choose a different strategy if it works better for you:

```
public class MyWorker extends ListenableWorker{

    private Context mContext;
    private FirebaseFirestore mDb;

    public MyWorker(Context context, WorkerParameters params){
        super(context, params);

        mContext = context; // Store the context passed into the worker
        mDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork(){

        return CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture(new CallbackToFutureAdapter.Resolver<Result>() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Object attachCompleter(@NonNull final CallbackToFutureAdapter.Completer<Result> completer)
                    throws Exception {

                Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference> completeListener = new OnCompleteListener<DocumentReference>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentReference> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    // ...

                                    completer.set(Result.success());

                                }else{
                                    // Whether you return failure or retry here
                                    // depends on what makes the most sense for your situation
                                    completer.set(Result.failure());
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
                        data.put("some_data", someData);

                        mDb.collection("myCollection")
                            .add(data)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(completeListener);
                    }
                };

                new Thread(runnable).start();

                return runnable;
            }
        }
    }
}
```